# How can I create a wasm_bindgen Closure which captures a Rc<RefCell<_>> without moving out of it?

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, rust-wasm

I have state that needs to be mutated multiple times by JavaScript callbacks (it's a game, so input from the user needs to modify the game state). I can't seem to figure out how to do it though. This is the simplest example I can think of that demonstrates the problem I'm having:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen(start)]
pub fn run() {
    let data = Rc::new(RefCell::new(vec![0]));
    let closure = Closure::wrap(Box::new(&mut || {
        data.borrow_mut().push(0);
        console_log!("{data:?}");
    }) as Box<dyn FnMut()>);

    closure.forget();
}
```

I thought that using an `Rc` would make `data` live as long as it's used, but I get this error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:19:47
   |
19 |        let closure = Closure::wrap(Box::new(&mut || {
   |   _________________________________-_____________^
   |  |_________________________________|
   | ||
20 | ||         data.borrow_mut().push(0);
21 | ||         console_log!("{data:?}");
22 | ||     }) as Box<dyn FnMut()>);
   | ||     ^-                     - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   | ||_____||
   |  |_____|cast requires that borrow lasts for `'static`
   |        creates a temporary which is freed while still in use

error[E0597]: `data` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:20:9
   |
19 |       let closure = Closure::wrap(Box::new(&mut || {
   |                                   -             -- value captured here
   |  _________________________________|
   | |
20 | |         data.borrow_mut().push(0);
   | |         ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
21 | |         console_log!("{data:?}");
22 | |     }) as Box<dyn FnMut()>);
   | |______- cast requires that `data` is borrowed for `'static`
...
25 |   }
   |   - `data` dropped here while still borrowed
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Add `move` to your closure: `move || { … }`

Comment: @Jmb I need to re-use `data`. That's why I have it in a `Rc<RefCell<>>`.

Comment: Actually I'm realizing I probably should remove `&mut` from the closure, but that doesn't change the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rc` can make it live enough, but currently you're borrowing the `Rc` itself which is destroyed at the end of `run()`. You need to clone it, and move the clone into the closure:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen(start)]
pub fn run() {
    let data = Rc::new(RefCell::new(vec![0]));
    let closure = Closure::wrap(Box::new({
        let data = Rc::clone(&data);
        &mut move || {
            data.borrow_mut().push(0);
            console_log!("{data:?}");
        }
    }) as Box<dyn FnMut()>);

    closure.forget();
}
```

You also need to not borrow the closure itself, which is the reason for the "temporary value dropped while borrowed" error. Replace the `&mut move || {` with just `move || {`.