# Passing mutable struct to JavaScript callback and keep modifications in WebAssembly

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I'm trying to pass a struct from Rust to a JavaScript callback with `wasm_bindgen`. The JavaScript code should be able to call methods defined in Rust.

This is why [this guide](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/reference/arbitrary-data-with-serde.html#serializing-and-deserializing-arbitrary-data-into-and-from-jsvalue-with-serde) doesn't work in my case, as there only objects are passed (you cannot call methods defined in Rust on them), not with references to the actual object in "Rust-Memory".

So basically I have a `SomeStruct` in Rust:

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
// Note that SomeStruct must not implement the Copy trait, as in the not-minimal-example I have Vec<>s in the struct
pub struct SomeStruct {
    pub(crate) field_to_be_modified: i32,
}


#[wasm_bindgen]
impl SomeStruct {
    #[wasm_bindgen(constructor)]
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        set_panic_hook();

        Self {
            field_to_be_modified: 0,
        }
    }

    pub fn modify_field(&mut self, value: i32) {
        self.field_to_be_modified = value;
    }

    pub fn field(&self) -> i32 {
        self.field_to_be_modified
    }

    #[wasm_bindgen]
    pub async fn with_callback(&self, function_or_promise: JsValue) -> Result<JsValue, JsValue> {
        let mut s = SomeStruct::new();
        let function = function_or_promise.dyn_into::<Function>().map_err(|_| {
            JsError::new("The provided callback is not a function. Please provide a function.")
        })?;

        run_any_function(&mut s, function, vec![JsValue::from(1u32)]).await
    }
}
```

However, in order to turn `SomeStruct` into a [`JsValue`](https://docs.rs/wasm-bindgen/0.2.11/wasm_bindgen/struct.JsValue.html) I can pass to JavaScript, I need to clone it first (otherwise the `JsValue::from` call doesn't compile):

```
let args = Array::new();

// This is the reason modifications from JS aren't reflected in Rust, but without it JsValue::from doesn't work
let clone = my_struct.clone();

// my_struct is the first function argument
// TODO: JsValue::from only works when cloned, not on the original struct. Why?
// Best would be directly passing my_struct, as then modifications would work
// Passing a pointer to the struct would also be fine, as long as methods can be called on it from JavaScript
args.push(&JsValue::from(clone));

for arg in arguments {
    args.push(&arg);
}

// Actually call the function
let result = function.apply(&JsValue::NULL, &args)?;

// TODO: How to turn result back into a SomeStruct struct?

// Copying fields manually also doesn't work because of borrow checker:
// my_struct.field_to_be_modified = clone.field_to_be_modified;
```

Now I want to modify the `field_to_be_modified` within the callback passed to `with_callback`, so I'm calling `s_instance.modify_field(42);` from JavaScript:

```
import * as mve from './pkg/mve.js';

async function run() {
    let module = await mve.default();

    let s = new mve.SomeStruct();

    console.log("Initial value (should be 0):", s.field());

    await s.with_callback(function(s_instance, second_arg, third_arg) {
        // s_instance is of type SomeStruct, and is a COPY of s

        console.log("callback was called with parameter", s_instance, second_arg, third_arg);

        console.log("Current field value (should be 0):", s_instance.field());

        console.log("Setting field to 42");

        // This only modifies the copy
        s_instance.modify_field(42);

        console.log("Field value after setting (should be 42):", s_instance.field());

        console.log("end callback");

        // TODO: Directly calling methods on s also does not work either
        // Error: recursive use of an object detected which would lead to unsafe aliasing in rust
        //
        // s.modify_field(43);
    })

    console.log("This should be after \"end callback\"");

    // TODO: the original s is unchanged, so
    // this does not work, as the callback operated on the cloned s
    // TODO: How to make this work?
    console.log("Field value after callback (should be 42):", s.field());
}

run();
```

This callback obviously only changes the cloned value that was passed to it, so the final `s.field()` call yields `0`. However, I cannot

- read from the cloned value in Rust after the function is called because of borrow checker errors
- pass the actual object I want to modify, as only a copy works

So **the question is how I can modify `SomeStruct` in JavaScript and get it back in Rust**. I don't care whether it's unsafe or not, I just want it to work.

I also created a minimum example with the code from this question so you can quickly run it, see the [Git repo](https://github.com/xarantolus/rust-wasm-bindgen-stackoverflow-question):

```
git clone https://github.com/xarantolus/rust-wasm-bindgen-stackoverflow-question
```

Clone the repo, follow the installation steps for wasm-pack and execute the following to see the problem on your machine:

```
wasm-pack build --target web && python3 -m http.server
```

[I have also opened an issue for this problem](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/3091).

Comment: Maybe use of `Rc` could solve issue with sharing of struct between wasm and JS, this answer explains how to use `Rc` in `wasm-bindgen` https://stackoverflow.com/a/72881156/5396835. The `wasm-bindgen` example [Paint use Rc](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/blob/main/examples/paint/src/lib.rs#L20) shows for a full application.